# Null Value Error when running firestore security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am learning about firestore security rules and I cannot get my head around why my security rule is failing.

This is my data structure:
[image]

This is the rule which I am trying to run:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /company/{company} {
      allow create, read, write, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && 
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/developer/$(request.auth.uid)).data.is_admin == true             
    }
  }
}
```

This is my JSON payload from simulator:

```
{
  "uid": " sxTCUVtxcSSTIWicv7op10Cc3ff2",
  "token": {
    "sub": " sxTCUVtxcSSTIWicv7op10Cc3ff2",
    "aud": "test-123",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "phone_number": "",
    "name": "",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

YOu can see the `UID` matches the developer documentID.  This is the error which I receive.

> Error running simulation – Error: simulator.rules line [6], column [73]. Null value error.

Please guide me on what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON payload from the simulator shows a leading space in the "uid":

```
"uid": " sxTCUVtxcSSTIWicv7op10Cc3ff2",  
        ^Remove this space
```

It should work after the space is removed from your simulator input.

Comment: Oh my god!! That was stupid of me. And you are totally correct. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anyone reding this - check that hand-written or copy-pasted UID's in firebase do not contain leading or trailing spaces!!!
This exact thing bit me the other way.